# Joining data from Access and SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, join

I have one access table like this

```
id     FrstName     LastName     Status
=================================================
1      John          Smith          1
2      Mike          Black          0
```

This is table from Project 1. I have to work on Project 2 where I have SQL table.
In this project I need to combine data from access (Project 1) and data from SQL (Project 2).

Is there a way that I join table from SQL with table from access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link access database in SQL server over option **Linked Server** and then you can use that for querying.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Create a linked server in DB invironment, then create a SP to take care of it.
2. Get two DataSets for them, then merge two datatables into one based on ID.

Hope it gives you some idea.